# How to identify build-specific kernel files?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-source, android-kernel

The Linux kernel repository contains files for various supported architectures, but in actual build, not all files are used. If I have a modified Linux kernel source code, which contains all the files from the original tree but doesn't use them, how can I identify those files which are relevant to the build?.

P.S. - I have a kernel source for an android device, I'm trying to figure out only those files which are required by the build.

Comment: One way comes to my mind is to parse output of `make V=1` Why do you need that?

Comment: I'm working on my first custom Android ROM. That's why